# Why is Interlocked.Exchange triggering warning CS4014?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, task-parallel-library, compiler-warnings

The following reduced example generates this compiler warning:

> warning CS4014: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.

```
public class TaskInterlockedExchangeTest
{
    private Task _Task;

    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _Task, null);
        await _Task;
    }
}
```

The warning is raised on the line with the `Interlocked.Exchange` call. As far as I'm aware [`Interlocked.Exchange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337971%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not `async` so why on earth is the compiler triggering this warning? Right now this doesn't make any sense to me, so what am I missing?

We do treat warnings as errors so I'm trying to figure out how to fix this (short of disabling the warning around the offending code which I would only see as last resort).

This happens on VS2013 (update 5).

**Update**

I just discovered that the following avoids the warning:

```
public class TaskInterlockedExchangeTest
{
    private Task _Task;

    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        var t = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _Task, null);
        await _Task;
    }
}
```

So simply assigning the result to a local variable is sufficient.

Comment: Exchange returns Task, try to call another method that returns Task from `async` method maybe the same warning will appear.

Comment: You're ignoring the return value of `Interlocked`, which is a `Task`. Stop ignoring it, and the warning will go away :)

Comment: Also, you're (most probably) awaiting on `null`... You probably meant `var task = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _Task, null); if (task != null) await task;`

Comment: @Luaan reminder to self: *always be pedantic on SO* :-) I "fixed" my comment above ;)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: This was just a minimal example to reproduce the warning and not the actual production code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling the [generic overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337971.aspx) of `Interlocked.Exchange`:

```
public static T Exchange<T>(ref T location1, T value)
    where T : class
```

Which means the result of the call is a `Task`. The warning works as designed. It sees you're calling a function which returns a `Task`, so is potentially asynchronous, but you don't `await` its result.

The line:

```
Interlocked.Exchange(ref _Task, null);
```

Means the following:

- Replace whatever was in `_Task` with `null`
- Throw out the previous value (given to you as the return value of `Interlocked.Exchange`)

The following line:

```
await _Task;
```

*most probably* is the equivalent of:

```
await null;
```

And will go *boom*.

I say *most probably*, since there's a tiny possibility another thread wrote something into `_Task`, and you're going to `await` that.

I guess the real code you wanted to write is the following:

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
    var task = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _Task, null);

    if (task != null)
        await task;
}
```

Or, with .NET 4.6:

```
public async Task DoSomething()
    => await (Interlocked.Exchange(ref _Task, null) ?? Task.CompletedTask);
```

You may even get rid of the `async`:

```
public Task DoSomething()
    => Interlocked.Exchange(ref _Task, null) ?? Task.CompletedTask;
```

Comment: I'm aware that `_Task` is `null` in this example. It was the minimal code required to reproduce the warning.

Comment: Hm, I see. So it's enough that a method returns `Task` to be considered potentially asynchroneous (even through nothing about Interlocked.Exchange is async). Anyway, simply assigning the return value to a local variable (without actually doing anything with it) avoids the warning.

Comment: @ChrisWue exactly. but I'd say this logic is debatable when applied to generic return types, as your example shows.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I agree and so I have created [an issue about this on the Roslyn repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8988).